# JavaScript substring from an element

Tags: javascript

This is some simple JavaScript code I would like to implement, butit does not work.

I'm trying to get the file link inside the tag `file` but I think `innerHTML` does not work in this kind of situation, but I've given it a shot to try.

Could you guys help me with this? I know I'm missing something here.

```
[videoplayer id="one" file="/dir1/dir2/hi.mp4" width="333" height="333" /]


<script type="text/javascript">
var str = document.getElementById('one').innerHTML;
document.write(str.substr(0,str.length-1));
</script>
```

Comment: What is the `[videoplayer]` tag? What language are you using?

Comment: this is a wordpress plugin and I'm trying to extract the link automatically for every video.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `getAttribute()` to retrieve the value of the `file` attribute.

```
var str = document.getElementById('one').getAttribute('file');

alert( str );
```

Probably a good idea to also make sure the element was found:

```
var el = document.getElementById('one');

if( el ) {

    alert( 'Element was found!' );

    var str = el.getAttribute('file');

} else {

    alert( 'NO element was found' );

}

alert( str );
```

Comment: wow fast answer! this is my first time seeing something called getAttribute() let me try it Thanks!

Comment: @iMohammad: You're welcome. You could also try `.file` instead of `.getAttribute('file')`, but I don't know if that attribute shows up as a property.

Comment: I just tried it, still it does not extract and print the link. Kindly Could you try the code for me?

Comment: @iMohammad: Did you use an `alert()` instead of `document.write`? Also did you try my updated answer? Place another `alert()` inside the `if()` statement to make sure an element was found. There really isn't much information to work from in your question.

Comment: @AdamRackis: Good idea. I should really be more productive right now. :)

Comment: @RightSaidFred I just tried your code, I get a pop box that `No Element was found` it still cannot find the id `one` maybe because it's not a html tag? much appreciated :)

Comment: hmm yeah I think because this is not a html tag.

Comment: @iMohammad: Then what is it? Is it stored as a String somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

You use the `getAttribute` function:

```
var str = document.getElementById('one').getAttribute('file');
```

`innerHTML` only works if there is HTML code inside of the tags:

```
<foo>
  Hello!
</foo>
```

But that is not the case for you.